# splunk enterprise: failed to connect to HEC or to port 8088

Tags: port, splunk, amazon-kinesis-firehose

i installed splunk enterprise (single server) in roeder to connect it to AWS Kinesis.
i configured the HEC on port 8088, but kinesis failed to connect.
when checked with curl: 
curl -k  "Authorization: Splunk 5567e908-ec26-4e2d-a569-8c7f5ef7033f"  "https://localhost:8088/"
I got:
**404 Not Found**

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

when checked splunk by: splunk  cmd btool web list --debug|grep -i 808
I got only port 8089 and not 8088 at all.
how can I activate the HEC to listen to port 8088 ??

Answer (score 0):

From your example it looks like you’re missing the endpoint (either `/services/collector/event`. The 404 means you are connecting to the host one the correct port (otherwise you’d get a different error).